# How to read a string of n characters at a time from a stream?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to copy every four characters read from a file stream into an array of size four. 
for example ,k[0], k[1], k[2],k[3] have 4 characters each.

```
char k[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        fgets(&k[i],4, keyfile);
        printf("%c \n",k[i]);    
}
```

Comment: What is happening that qualifies as "not working"? Please describe your problem in more detail. A more complete example of code that includes the declaration of`k` would be good, too.

Comment: `char buf[n]; while(fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, stdin) == 1) do_stuff(buf);`

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` gets an entire string. Use `fgetc` instead.
Alternatively, ditch the for-loop.

Comment: `scanf` and keeping the loop would also be an option.

Comment: `fgets()` gets a _line_ of characters, not a string, up to and including a final `'\n'`.  It does not stop reading should it encounter a null character `'\0'`.  When done, it appends a null character insuring what was read is now a string.